# Group particles not showing up in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, groups

i'm currently having trouble with a project i'm working on. I can't quite get this object group to emit from this plane as a particle system.

[image: Empty plane]

The group is on the 2nd layer. Here's the blend file: http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=49654

Comment: Turn off interpolated children in children tab, or, if you want it, use hair particles instead, which is what I would actually suggest for this type of particle system. You should also apply the scale of the ground and the rotation of the grass.

Comment: Okay so I did everything you said... but now for some reason the clumps of grass are floating above the plane???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix it, but I suggest watching some tutorials how to create grass in Blender.

Usually it's done with hair particles, either by manipulating the hair 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mZR_WKVYiX8

or duplicating mesh grass using the hair particles
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eshOzshjt90&t=58s

[image]